# Not able to install modules

Tags: installation

I installed Drupal on my localhost (LAMP Stack), and I am trying to install modules, but I get the following error.

[image]

I tried changing the permissions of the folder, but still it is not working. It is showing same error from both the methods of installation.

Comment: Did you check the permission and owner of `sites` folder, can you add the result of `ls ali .`  of the ligne end with `sites`  ?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx  3 akshay akshay   4096 Dec  5 17:28 sites
@berramou

Comment: This isn't related to file permissions. The warning is telling you that the FTP connection you're using is not secure, and that your username and password will be sent plaintext with the request. To fix properly, stop using this interface, and use Composer (or possibly Drush for D7) to manage your modules.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, but a warning reminding you that you aren't using an encrypted connection, and that the credentials you are using (username and password) could be read from somebody who can intercept the data exchanged between your computer and the server. If you look at the protocol used for the page, you will notice it's http://, not https://.
It's not an error caused from the file/directory permissions.

If you don't have a SSL certificate, just enter username and password that are accepted from the FTP server, and install the modules. The warning is just suggesting that using a secure communication would be preferable.

You could also avoid Drupal prompts for FTP/SSH credentials by setting the owner of the temporary:// directory (and its subdirectories) to the owner of the sites/default directory (which, in your case, I take is *akshay*).